# svn change source respository

Tags: svn

I have checked out code from a svn repository and started making changes. But now the repository has been renamed. How do I map my local repository to the newly named source repository and then run svn commands on it.

Comment: A google search for the title of this question yields a variety of helpful answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Subversion 1.6 or lower, use [svn switch --relocate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)
For Subversion 1.7 or later, use [svn relocate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html)

Comment: Thank you!  Seriously, I wish I'd found that way back when.  I was editing my (previously horrible) answer when you posted yours.